# Random code suddenly appears in all php files

Tags: php, iis, windows-server-2008-r2

This random code appears in all php files on a windows server 2008 using php with IIS and i dont know why, any sugestions?

[image]

Comment: Web site is hacked. I can tell by the `isset($_GLOBALS[ x61`. **Source** Worked at a large web-host for many years, have seen exact same exploit thousands of times. [Run some code through this site](https://www.unphp.net/)

Comment: It seems your server was infected. I suggest to restore a backup and search for vulnerabilities.